# How to convert an integer to a floating point value in x86 ASM?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

I need to multiply an integer (two's compliment) by a floating point constant. Here is what I have:

```
.data
pi  dd 3.14
int dd 0ah


.code
fld pi

???

fmul ST(1), ST
```

How can I convert `int` to a floating point value for multiplying against `pi`?

Comment: You may want to use the fldpi instruction..

Comment: Isn't that obvious? You get pi 'for free'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need the `fild` instruction. Here's one reference: http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap5.htm

Comment: Great! And when were these instructions added to the x86 instruction set? (like with the 386/7, the 486/7...?)

Comment: @NathanOsman: Most of them were added with 8087.  sin/cos/tan instructions were new with 387, and possibly some other transcendental functions (exp / log instructions).  `fimul dword [int]` is available if x87 is available at all; no need to use a separate `fild`. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fmul:fmulp:fimul

Answer (score 0):

Using the x86 FPU is really outdated now and way slower than SSE/AVX/etc.

Better to use at least SSE with `cvtdq2ps`[doc](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtepi32_ps&expand=1449,1449)

ex:

```
.data
int dd 0ah
pi  dd 3.14

.code
movss xmm0, [data] ; load 32bit data into xmm0
cvtdq2ps xmm0, xmm0 ; convert 4 float values to integers, we use only lowest float/integer
mulss xmm0, [pi]
```

Comment: For asm, it makes more sense to link asm docs, not the intrinsics guide.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtdq2ps.  And BTW, yes `movss` (or `movd`) + `cvtdq2ps` is actually equal or better to the more obvious `cvtsi2ss xmm0, dword [int]`.  That costs more uops to merge with the old value (because of Intel's poor / short-sighted design to not zero the rest of the xmm destination), and thus has a false dependency unless you spend and extra uop to xor-zero xmm0 first.