# Dividing longfloat and int in Assembly x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, fpu, x87

I have a program where i loop for as long as the user enters Y (for yes).  The user then inputs data of type long float.  I also have a counter, r14, which will count each time they input a long float.  After the loop ends, i wish to calculate the mean.  if i do this:

```
fld tword [r14]
```

and display it, ill get a segmentation fault.  Ive tried a bunch of other things too but it always gives me a seg. fault after attempting to divide and display.  I think the problem is that r14 is an int, and i cannot put it into the FPU stack like that and divide.  But i cant figure out another way.

can someone help please?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer to a floating point value in x86 ASM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027424/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-floating-point-value-in-x86-asm)

Answer (score 0):

FPU instructions take their arguments either from memory or from FPU registers, but not from general-purpose CPU registers.

`fld tword [r14]` takes a `tword` from a memory location at the address contained in `r14` and pushes it on top of the FPU stack.

If `r14` does not point to a memory location that a 10-byte floating point value can be read from, you get a segmentation fault.

So, store your float in memory and read it from there with `fld`.

Comment: i dont quite understand.  i have already loaded my float with fld while inside a loop.  but it wont perform a division operation with the counter. is there another way , like fild that i should load?