# Dividing and rounding in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I have two numbers (DWORD number_A and DWORD number_B). I am unsure of how to go about dividing the two to get a decimal number, rounded to the nearest thousandth.

(ie)

```
DWORD number_A 20
DWORD number_B 10
```

A/B = 2.00 is the format for the answer I'm trying to get.

How do I go about dividing and then displaying the answer like above in assembly language? We are also using the irvine library, if that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027424/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-floating-point-value-in-x86-asm maybe this would offer some help

Comment: Does your course require you to use legacy x87, or can you use SSE2 `cvtsi2sd` and `divsd` to convert to `double` in XMM registers?  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsi2sd

Comment: 2.00 would be rounded to hundredth? You can use fixed-point arithmetic, calculate the division with integers (e.g. use cents instead of dollars), but output with a . in between. Before the division you have to multiply by 100/1000 (see @Chris Halls answer line 3). For output you can divide by 100/1000 with remainder, and put a decimal point in between.

Comment: @Sebastian: FWIW, if you multiply by 100/1000 before dividing by B, the division can fail if B < 100/1000 and A is large enough.  I have extended my answer to discuss that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this using integer arithmetic, then (Method 1):

```
  q = A / B      -- integer division  ) assuming unsigned numbers, that's
  r = A % B      -- integer remainder ) q = eax and r = edx after a DIV

  r = r * 1000
  f = r / B      -- also integer division/remainder, as above
  r = r % B

  f += ((r * 2) >= B)  -- where >= returns 0 or 1

  if (f > 999) { q += 1 ; f = 0 ; }
```

then output `q`, followed by '.', followed by 3 digits for `f` complete with leading zeros, as required.

---

You can also do the rounding and fraction part as follows (Method 2):

```
  q = A / B          -- as above
  r = A % B

  r = r * 2000
  f = r / B          -- result f is in half-thousandths
  f = (f + 1) >> 1   -- round to nearest thousandth

  if (f > 999) { q += 1 ; f = 0 ; }
```

In this and the previous form, if `B` is (very) large, the `r * 2000` (and indeed `r * 1000`) may be more that 32 bits -- but that's OK because `DIV` will cope with a 64-bit dividend, provided the quotient is less than 2^32 -- and we know the quotient in this case is less than 2000 (or 1000).

---

As noted elsewhere you can also do this (Method 3):

```
  A = A * 1000
  q = A / B
  r = A % B

  q += ((r * 2) >= B)  -- where >= returns 0 or 1

  f = q % 1000         -- alternatively, when outputting, convert f to  
  q = q / 1000         -- decimal and insert '.' before last 3 digits
```

And, alternatively (Method 4):

```
  q = (A * 2000) / B   -- again half-thousandths
  q = (q + 1) >> 1     -- round to nearest thousandth
```

**BUT:** the division will fail if `A * 1000` (or `A * 2000`) is greater than or equal to `B * 2^32` -- because `q` is, then, greater than or equal to 2^32.

The advantage of Methods 1 and 2 is that they are not tripped up in this way.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `f = (f + 1) >> 1` and the later fixup of the whole part is doing rounding to nearest-even instead of truncating.

Comment: @PeterCordes: the `f = (f + 1) >> 1` (Method 2) has `f` in half-thousandths, so this adds a half-thousandth (` + 1`) and truncates to thousandths (` >> 1`), to do conventional round to nearest (ie not round to nearest-even).  (Likewise Method 4.)

Comment: Oh right.  Worth explaining that in your answer, IMO, and maybe even showing a simple version that lets truncation happen.

Comment: @PeterCordes: OK -- added some comments re half-thousandths.  OP asked for "rounded to the nearest thousandth"... so not convinced that showing how to truncate to thousandths brings much to the party.

Comment: I missed that phrasing.  It's likely the OP is a beginner doing homework that doesn't know the difference between rounding and truncation, and was just thinking in terms of getting a result with 3 places after the decimal somehow.  That's why I thought it might be useful to show a simple version that doesn't incorporate round to nearest.  But sure, this is more than fine as a recipe.  I might have included some text to at least point out that rounding to nearest takes more work than truncation, and how this accomplishes that.  But then it would have taken too much effort to answer this. :/